# What is the rule for manipulating the boundaries of a summation?

Tags: discrete-signals, z-transform

When working with DTFTs or $\mathcal Z$-transforms, we sometime get summations that do not go from $n=0$ to $+\infty$. 
For example, suppose we have the sequence $x(n) = -\alpha^n u(-n-1)$. To find the $\mathcal Z$-transform:
\begin{align}
X(z)&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x(n)z^{-n}\\
&=-\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} \alpha^nz^{-n}
\end{align}

I understand this, the step function(which was shifted and inverted) causes the sequence to exist for all values from $-\infty$ to $-1$, and is $0$ everywhere else. However, the next part of the solution confuses me:
$$=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\alpha^{-1}z)^{n+1}  $$
I am not sure how they managed to change the boundaries.

- From my interpretation of the result , a flip of the boundaries $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}$ to $\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}$ for any sequence will cause the sign of $n$ to change. Is this true?
- Then, to get from $\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}$ to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$,do you just need to add $1$ to wherever here is an $n$?
- Should you always first flip the boundary (when necessary) and then only change the index afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summations are not like integrals. When you calculate an integral, swapping the boundaries *does* change the sign of the result. However, when talking about summations:

$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}a(n)=\sum_{n=-1}^{-\infty}a(n)$$

This holds because it is the same if we perform the sum of $a(-1)+a(-2)+...+a(-k)$ for any $k>0$ in any order. Namely, you can order those terms as you wish as long as all the terms are present. For infinite summations, this is true [if the series is absolutely convergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885329/why-does-the-order-of-summation-of-the-terms-of-an-infinite-series-influence-its).

In your example, they just made the change of variables $m=-n-1$ to get the summation from $0$ to $+\infty$. It may be confusing because they kept the original name of the index ($n$) instad of replacing it with the new one ($m$), but remember that they are just indexes or dummy variables, so in the end it doesn't matter. You can check that if $m=-n-1=-(n+1)$, then the boundaries change:

$$n=-1 \to m=-(-1+1)=0$$
$$n=-\infty \to m=-(-\infty)=\infty$$

where I used the fact that a finite number is negligible against infinity. So the summation can be written as:

$$\begin{align} -\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} \alpha^nz^{-n}&=-\sum_{m=\infty}^{0} \alpha^{-(m+1)}z^{-(-(m+1))}\\
&=-\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \alpha^{-(m+1)}z^{-(-(m+1))}\\
&=-\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \alpha^{-(m+1)}z^{m+1}\\
&=-\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (\alpha^{-1}z)^{m+1}
\end{align}$$

And that's the same result you wrote in your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for you explanation! I understand it now. I was getting very confused when working with similar examples. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Glad to help! :)